# Call External Javascript using php

Tags: php, javascript

I am try to add a javascript using php as follows

```
<?php
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
$serverIP=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo "document.write(\"Your IP address is: <b>" . $serverIP . "</b>\")";
?>
```

Here i need to print my output as follows

> Your IP address is: **127.0.0.1**

but it is showing result like

```
document.write("Your IP address is: <b>127.0.0.1</b>").
```

i am using apache server in ubuntu.What is wrong with me. help me please...

Comment: Where are you including this snippet and how?

Comment: you know, it would be very helpful if you would actually explain in detail what you are doing, instead of having five people guessing what your problem could be.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code

```
<?php
$serverIP=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo "<script>document.write(\"Your IP address is: <b>" . $serverIP . "</b>\")</script>";
?>
```

I tried it at my end and it worked

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by pointy, you need to wrap js code in `script` tags. Also you can get users' IP with PHP without resorting to JS:

```
echo 'Your IP address is: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

**Update:**

Try this:

```
<?php
header("content-type: text/javascript");
$serverIP=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo "<script>document.write(\"Your IP address is: <b>" . $serverIP . "</b>\")</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Sarfraz...But unfortunately actually I need to do as I mention above.

Answer (score 0):

Try `header('Content-Type: application/javascript');`

Comment: Thank you for your response.Extremely sorry to disturb you this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the mime content type to **application/javascript**

Comment: Thank you for your response.I changed my mime content as you suggested.but unfortunately it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from fixing the header as suggestted above, how are you adding this to your html document?  Presumably the html has a script tag, which then references this php script.  And presumably that is somewhere within the body of your html....

```
<html>
<body>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="showipaddress.php"></script> 
<p>blah</p>
etc
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the `<script>` tags.

```
echo "<script>document.write(\"Your IP address is: <b>" . $serverIP . "</b>\");</script>";
```

Comment: i think when we are using following there is no need to add script tag
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");but,when i try to add above it is also not working.showing same result.

Comment: I don't believe that you can feed a server a Javascript source like that. Try setting the content type to "text/html" instead.